# How to subsurf this wing without adding vertices to its profile (only to the curvature)

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have this wing:

[image]

How can I subsurf it with only adding cuts between the ones selected, without adding vertices to its profile that already has more than 120?
I can Loop Cut, but then I'll have to manually move the new cuts and scale them, which will not result in a smooth curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Beveling Edge Loop:

Choose **Edge Select** mode and select desired **Edge Loops** (like you have in your screenshot now) then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to **Bevel**, you can set amount of **Edge Loops** by hand (mouse scroll and move) or just by tweaking values in **Tools Panel** or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image: Loop]

### Loft with LoopTools:

This method will allow you to add the same number of **Loops** between existing ones. You need to turn on **LoopTools** addon in **User Preference** menu.

Select all **Edges** between **Loops**, delete them, then select remaining **Edge Loops**, hit <kbd>W</kbd> > **LoopTools** > **Loft** and change values accordingly.

Sadly there is not (or I'm not aware of it) any automatic method to give same space between all Edge Loops given that there is different space with existing ones. You can just put same amount of cuts. As a workaround you can make two things. First one is kind a eye-balling, so it's not perfect.

[image: Loop_2]

### Spacing Manually by Loop Cuts:

In this method you will need to place **Loop Cuts** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > <kbd>MouseScroll</kbd>) manually and eye-balling number of cuts. It could give pretty nice result with a little of practice.

[image: Loop_3]

### Dissolving and adding new cuts:

This one is a last option, this will give even spacing but will not preserve main shape and you will need to manually move **Edge Loops** with **Proportional Editing** turned on.

Select existing **Edge Loops**, **Dissolve Edges**, add **Loop Cuts**, move new **Edge Loops** with **Proportional Editing** turned on (<kbd>MouseScroll</kbd> to control influance).

[image: Loop_4]

Comment: This only smoothens the loops themselves. What I want is that the whole wing curvature becomes smooth by having even spaces between loops. But I can still make use of this method. If you have any better idea please post it as another answer

Comment: @tooniis Oh, ok, I've misunderstood your question then. I'll delete this one/or edit, and if I can make what you need I will post it soon.

Comment: @Tooniis check my edit. They are all I can think off now. Also little off-topic  but I would recommend for you to make mesh with less face (low poly) and then add Subsurface Modifier to smooth things out. It's just easier to control things.

Comment: Loft does not work well on my wing and it makes a mess. I'll try the last option as it seems it is the best option.

Comment: @Tooniis you don't need to Loft all of the Edge Loops at once. Take them by the straight parts, without hard angles.

Comment: that's exactly what I did. Anyway I was able to get a decent result by beveling and some loop cuts that were manually positioned. The "Spacing Manually by Loop Cuts" solution cannot help me at all, because what I want is a subsurf effect on my curved not straight wing without adding vertices to the profile. If you tried with a curved wing like mine then you might have found better solutions.

Comment: @Tooniis could you upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? I'll take closer look at this.